# Driver installation failed despite test mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, drivers, digital-signature

I have test mode enabled. But still, I get the message that the driver couldn't be installed (Code 52).

Context: I'm trying to connect a TI84+ with my Windows 7 PC with an USB cable to transfer files, specifically an assembly program, an operating system and a backup of another calculator.

I went to the device manager, chose "update driver". Automatic failed, search on PC with folder failed (even when searching the entire C drive), search on PC with list finds something, but that fails. It tells me that the driver has a signature (that's probably because of the test mode), but after trying it tells me that it failed because of the missing signature.

What to do to REALLY enforce installing unsigned drivers?

Comment: What "test mode"? Test mode usually implies some special handling. Did you try your drivers without "test mode"? Did you try not to "find something", but get explicit drivers for this device from the manufacturer, Texas Instruments?

Comment: Test mode: That thing is called "Windows test mode", it's the official name. The command is "bcdedit /set TESTSIGNING ON". It should in theory install unsigned drivers. Yes, I tried it without first, in different combinations, without success. Yes, I searched for the drivers, but I can't get the driver alone, it always directs me to the TI Connect download page. If you have a link, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, you need to download and install "TI Connect software", https://education.ti.com/en/customer-support/download_stepbystep

Comment: I did that. I uninstalled and installed it again multiple times, but that didn't help.

Comment: Btw, I just tried to install a driver, it complained about the missing signature, I started test mode and it worked. So I'm not entering the command wrongly or something like that, it's the correct test mode.